# Young adult novel with dragons, magic, and ends weirdly

Tags: story-identification, books, magic, young-adult, dragons

In elementary school, between '92 and '96, I read a young adult fantasy novel that has eluded my internet searches to this day. I don't remember the plot, but I think it had the word 'Rainbow' in the title. There was a dragon that the main character, and adventuring party, was flying on at the end of the book. The bad guys (?) cast a magical web in front of the dragon at the end of the book, and the characters fell. It just stopped there! It was probably part of a series. I can't remember much else. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Would it be one of the Xanth series? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xanth#Books

Comment: Maybe this list will spark a memory: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_dragons_in_literature

Comment: Greg Costikyan had a series of 2 books (never finished) and I think I remember the 2nd one ending like this.  [One Quest, Hold the Dragon](https://www.amazon.com/Quest-Hold-Dragons-Cups-Sorcery/dp/0812522699)

Comment: I have a strong feeling that there is a scene like the one described here, in one of Barbara Hambly's Dragonsbane sequels (not Dragonsbane itself iirc).  I do not have access to a copy to check if this is correct, and, if so, which book.  Perhaps someone out there has a copy?

Answer (score 7):

This is a long shot - but the 1993 novel '[The Iron Dragon's Daughter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Iron_Dragon%27s_Daughter)' by Michael Swanwick has a chase scene near the end of the book, in which

> the protagonist, a girl named Jane, and her dragon Melanchthon are being pursued by other 'dragon pilots' (in this world, dragons are magical/mechanical, somewhat malevolent constructs). They do fall, as do their adversaries, after being slowly destroyed by the environment through which they are travelling (a 'super-reality' in which the goddess of their existence resides).

However, Iron Dragon's Daughter does not end at that point, but continues for two chapters of resolution, so, again, it is a long shot. Also, it was not written for young adults, so if you read it in elementary school there could be quite a few bits that didn't quite sink in.

Incidentally, Swanwick wrote a sequel, The Dragons of Babel, in 2008.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is Laurence Yep's series:

- Dragon of the Lost Sea (1982)
- Dragon Steel (1985)
- Dragon Cauldron (1991)
- Dragon War (1992)

"Rainbow" probably comes from the dragon's name: Shimmer. The adventuring group is her, Thorn (a human boy), Monkey (pulled right out of Journey to the West along with his magic staff), Civet ( a witch), and Indigo (a human girl).

I remember a flaming net being part of the books too. Unfortunately, I can only find the last three right now. I don't think it was from the first one anyway. In the second book, there is a large wire-mesh flaming bird at the beginning and at the end of the underwater segment. In the third one, near the end, the bad guy casts a spell to keep the dragon from flying, and the same bad guy comes back about 60 pages later, at the very end.

Dragon War has a few scenes that are similar, but also has a proper denouement, so I doubt that's the one you read.

Answer (score -1):

Could it be one of the [Dragonriders of Pern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronological_list_of_Pern_books) series by Anne McCaffrey?

Comment: It doesn't sound like any of the ones I've read...

Comment: Far off the mark. The above does not describe the Pern series at all. There while there are dragons, there is no magic in Pern.

Comment: Casting a pretty broad net by bringing that series up